# Toilet running constantly after replacing parts

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I'm looking for any thoughts or guidance on this as I am officially out of patience:) Here's what I have done, step by step (sorry, this is long...):

Our toilet was running a bit, so we replaced the very old fill valve. All was great, but occasionally we were having some issues with the flapper chain getting caught up and causing the toilet to run A LOT, so I thought I would also replace the flush valve since that part was also really old. I bought an all-in-one repair kit (which for the record claimed to be a simple installation, and was most definitely not:) The all in one kit had a new fill valve, new flush valve, flapper, gasket, etc. The whole rig.

When I removed the tank and replaced everything, the new kit came with a single round rubber gasket, but the gasket that I removed from the old flush valve was a different style- it had three rubber 'stoppers' that inserted into the bolt holes for the tank in addition to the gasket that went around the flush valve. Since the kit said it was 'universal', I didn't think it would matter and installed everything as per the instructions. Once I did that, the toilet leaked horribly out of the bolt holes onto the floor. After trying everything, I found out that our toilet being a Kohler meant that it should have had the same style gasket with the rubber stoppers inserted into the bolt holes. So I went and bought a replacement Kohler gasket, removed the tank (again), installed the new gasket onto the flush valve that came in the universal kit (which meant that I had to use the lock nut that came with the universal kit, not the one that came with the Kohler gasket b/c that didn't fit the shaft of the flush valve), used the new bolts/washers, reattached the tank, cut on the water and YES- no more leaking on the floor.

But, now the tank fills to the correct level, runs water into the bowl until it hits the refill level, and fills. CONSTANTLY. I've checked the overflow pipe, and it's not so low that the water level is above it. I also tried replacing the fill valve with the previous one we had that was new a couple months ago, and it's doing the same thing. I don't think it's a flapper issue because when I push down on the flapper it still runs.

SO... is it possible that using the rubber gasket that didn't come with the kit is causing it to run? It's definitely not leaking onto the floor, just into my tank. Is there anything else I can try? I've spent 2 days and about 6 hours trying to fix this thing, and I'm on the verge of just buying a new toilet, but I really don't want to let this thing defeat me...

Comment: if its running but not going in the overflow or past the flapper then where is the water going?  Best take a good look underneath to see if its running onto the floor.  (Could be a trickle running past the tank bolts)

Comment: So the running water is going into the toilet bowl, right? Did you install a new seat for the flapper valve? Could the water be running out between the new seat (or the bottom of the overflow tube) and the china tank?

Comment: Two things. 1) I'm assuming you *did* use an old dish sponge to clean the port the flapper opens and closes, right? If not, this may be your problem. The slimy buildup around the rim of that port prevents the flapper from making a seal. 2) If it's a mystery where the water is going, put a few drops of food coloring in the tank and get a look, although I would assume it's making its way down into the bowl. My hunch is you just need to clean the flapper port. (Kohler fittings though? I'll save my rant about Kohler for another day. ::cough::pressure balancing valve!!!::cough::)

Comment: Thanks all! So, the water is definitely running into the bowl. 100% sure, because it's running quite a bit and I can see it and hear it flowing into the bowl. Not running onto the floor at all. I did use a toothbrush and clean all around the bolt holes, but I actually didn't clean around the flush valve, so I will try that. I live at the beach so there's always a lot of buildup due to salt and rust so could be the issue. Yes @elrobis, no comment on the Kohler situation- we 'inherited' this toilet when we bought the house, so next time I buy a toilet (hopefully not today), I'm switching!

Comment: i gather you replaced the flapper seat ( probably held by a big plastic nut under the tank ). It may be leaking between the seat fixture and the tank. Take apart, clean good (The side inside the tank) Make sure you put the gaskets in the right order.

Comment: @BrookeScarborough...based on your response, I am optimistic that scrubbing that flapper valve/port should solve the problem. Also FYI, if you are on septic (guessing not if you're at the beach, but others with septic may find this thread), continuously running water into a septic field is bad for it, so make sure your stop valves are closed in the meantime!

Comment: Jim or elrobis take credit and make an answer +

Comment: Thanks all. I'm fairly positive it's due to Kohler parts not playing nice with the other replacement parts, and since nowhere carries Kohler parts, I went and bought a new toilet last night. It did in fact defeat me :/